# Components in JDialog not showing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

First of all: I know this question seems to have been asked a few million times, but none of the answers given to other questions seem to work with me.

Sometimes, when I run `Message.popup(String, int)` in the code below, the text displays correctly, but sometimes the JDialog is empty, like if the component wasn't added at all.

```
public class Message extends JDialog {
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private JLabel content;

    public Message(String _content, int _margin) {
        super();
        this.content = new JLabel(_content);
        content.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 20));
        this.margin = _margin;
        this.width = content.getPreferredSize().width + _margin;
        this.height = content.getPreferredSize().height + _margin;

        createComponents();
        setProperties();
    }

    public static void popup(String _content, int _time) {
      if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        runPopup(_content, _time);
      }
      else {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            runPopup(_content, _time);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    private static void runPopup(String _content, int _time) {
      final Message message = new Message(_content);
      new Timer(_time, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          message.dispose();
        }
      }).start();
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        add(box);
    }

    private void setProperties() {
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocation(Coordinator.calculateCenteredWindowLocation(width, height));
        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle(content.getText());
        setVisible(true);
        update(getGraphics());
    }
}
```

Without the `update(getGraphics());`, the frame is always empty, but with it, it depends of what direction the wind is blowing... (go figure!)

Comment: "..sometimes the JFrame is empty"  What JFrame?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) (as might have been mentioned a few thousand times on those millions of threads you researched).

Comment: @Andrew Sorry about that, I updated the code and it now extends JDialog and not JFrame. My bad! The change has been made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Riduidel, it is important that anything Swing-related occur on the Event Dispatch Thread, or `EDT`. This is because Swing is not thread-safe. When invoking `popup()`, you ought to do the following

```
if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){
    Message.popup(...);
}
else{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Message.popup(...);
        }
    });
}
```

This will ensure that the `JFrame` is created on the `EDT`. Also, from the code snippet you've posted, it would seem likely that `Message` should have a private constructor. In addition, since you're not doing any custom rendering, why not just make a `JFrame` member variable instead of extending the class? -- seems a bit superfluous to me.

Regardless, you should also never `sleep` in the `EDT` either, since this will make the GUI appear to "freeze" and blocks execution of other queued events. When performing long-running tasks, use either [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), or as @Riduidel mentioned, [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). But if you prefer to use the [`java.util.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), use the [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) utility class as shown above to post the `Runnable` task on the `EventQueue` to be executed in the `EDT`.

**EDIT**

Here is what I'd do (and yes, it works)

```
public class Message {

    // Private constructor to prevent external instantiation
    private Message(){
    }

    public static void createAndShowDialog(final String content, final int time){
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(content);
        label.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 20));

        Box b = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        b.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        b.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        b.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        dialog.add(b);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        // kick-off timer
        Timer t = new Timer(time, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              dialog.dispose();
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

And wherever you invoke `createAndShowDialog(...)`, do the following

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Message.createAndShowDialog("Content", 5000); // wait 5 seconds before disposing dialog
    }
});
```

Comment: @mre I realize now that I know nothing about Swing ;-) Thanks a lot for all the informations around the question!

Comment: @Oltarus, if you're still having trouble, let me know! :)

Comment: @mre I'm still having trouble. I did what you said, including the Timer stuff, but sometimes, it's still not displaying. If it can help to understand, the text that **is** displayed disappears when I minimize/restore the frame.

Comment: Your if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) saved me big time today!!

Comment: @StephaneGrenier, Good to hear! :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your code is executing in the [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) ? indeed, if not (which is what I expect to be, since you `sleep` the current thread, what Swing would typically don't like), your frame will have trouble rendering.

To avoid those typical Swing threading issues, please take a look at the [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) class, which provide you methods to ensure you're running in EDT. Additionnaly, instead of directly sleeping your thread, you could repalce it with a Swing [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (beware not to confuse it with the `java.util.Timer`).

Answer (score 2):

```
update(getGraphics());
```

Never use the update() method or the getGraphics() method.

Invoking update() is used for AWT NOT Swing.

If you need to do custom painting then you override the paintComponent() method of your component which already has access to the graphics object.